# Is there an equivalent to ofoldlUnwrap for scanl-ing unboxed vectors?

Tags: haskell, fold

Is there a way to use a `Control.Foldl` from `foldl` as a `scanl` over an unboxed or generic `vector`?

It's definitely possible to use `purely ofoldlUnwrap` to fold over the unboxed vector as suggested in the `foldl` documentation. But the same is not possible for scans.

The naive approach fails because there is (at least to my knowledge) no way to set the type of the intermediate result:

```
scanVG :: forall v a b . (VG.Vector v a, VG.Vector v b)
       => F.Fold a b -> v a -> v b
scanVG (F.Fold step begin done)  = VG.map done . VG.scanl' step begin

===>

• Could not deduce (Vector v x) arising from a use of ‘map’
  from the context: (Vector v a, Vector v b)
    bound by the type signature for:
               scanVG :: (Vector v a, Vector v b) => Fold a b -> v a -> v b
    at src/File.hs:(162,1)-(163,34)
  Possible fix:
    add (Vector v x) to the context of the data constructor ‘Fold’
• In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map done’
  In the expression: map done . scanl' step begin
  In an equation for ‘scanVG’:
      scanVG (Fold step begin done) = map done . scanl' step begin
```

Right now I am converting to and from a boxed vector and hope that fusion get's rid of the overhead involved.

Comment: It seems that the problem is caused by the fact that the "inner" parameter of Fold can be anything. Thus, constrained functions (i.e. unboxed vector map and scanl) can not be used as consumers of it. To support this point, we can construct a similar datatype that can be consumed just as you describe: `data FoldlUnboxed a b = forall x . VG.Unbox x => FoldlUnboxed (x -> a -> x) x (x -> b)` can be processed with `scanVG (FoldlUnboxed step begin done) v = VG.map done . VG.scanl' step begin $ v`

Comment: That works, but does not allow `Folds` to be converted to `FoldlUnboxed`, does it?

Comment: It does not so it's probably of no real use for you.